# Printing the sum of prime divisors of each number in a given range in python

Tags: python

Here's my code for printing the sum of prime divisors of each number between 18 to 25. But it is only printing 5.

For example:

18 has prime factors 2, 3 hence sum = 5,

19 is prime, hence sum of factors = 0,

20 has prime factors 2 and 5, hence sum = 7,

21 has prime factors 3 and 7, hence sum = 10,

22 has prime factors 2 and 11, hence sum = 13,

23 is prime. hence sum = 0,

24 has prime factors 2 and 3, hence sum = 5,

25 has prime factor 5, hence sum = 5

Therefore, it should print [5,0,7,10,13,0,5,5]
I believe I should use break statement but i tried it didn't work. As I am beginner in python, any kind of help much appreciated.

```
def isPrime(n):
i = 2
while i * i <= n:

# n has a factor, hence not a prime 
  if (n % i == 0):
      return False
    i += 1
      
# we reach here if n has no factors 
# and hence n is a prime number 
return True
  
def summ(l, r):
summ = 0
arrayofdivisors = []
arrayofsum = []

# iterate from lower to upper 
for i in range(l, r + 1) :

    # if i is prime, it has no factors 
    if (isPrime(i)) :
        continue
    for j in range(2, i):

        # check if j is a prime factor of i 
        if (i % j == 0 and isPrime(j)) :
            
            arrayofdivisors.append(j)
            
            if(len(arrayofdivisors)>1):
             ans = sum(arrayofdivisors)
            
             arrayofsum.append(ans)
             
        
    return arrayofsum
    
   
 # Driver code
 if __name__ == "__main__":
 l = 18
 r = 25
 print(summ(l, r))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost impossible to tell because of the way you've formatted things, but the problem here is that your "return" statement is indented one position too far.  Thus, you return at the end of the first loop, before it has a chance to check anything else.  Un-indent the `return arrayofsum` and it should work.

Then, you are initializing `arrayofdivisors` outside the main loop, so it just kept getting larger and larger.  Then, you weren't adding `0` to the list for prime numbers, as your spec required.

Note that `if` statements in Python do not need parentheses, like they do in C.

```
def isPrime(n):
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:

        # n has a factor, hence not a prime 
        if n % i == 0:
            print(n,'not prime')
            return False
        i += 1
          
    # we reach here if n has no factors 
    # and hence n is a prime number 
    print(n,"prime")
    return True
      
def summ(l, r):

# iterate from lower to upper 
    arrayofsum = []
    for i in range(l, r + 1) :
        arrayofdivisors = []

        # if i is prime, it has no factors 
        if isPrime(i):
            arrayofsum.append(0)
            continue
        for j in range(2, i):
            # check if j is a prime factor of i 
            if i % j == 0 and isPrime(j):
                arrayofdivisors.append(j)
                
        arrayofsum.append( sum(arrayofdivisors) )
            
    return arrayofsum
        
       
# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = 18
    r = 25
    print(summ(l, r))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for specifying the mistake in such detail.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
def isPrime(n) :
   if (n <= 1) :
     return False
   if (n <= 3) :
      return True

   if (n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0) :
      return False

   i = 5
   while(i * i <= n) :
      if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0) :
        return False
      i = i + 6

   return True


def Sum(N):

  SumOfPrimeDivisors = [0] * (N + 1)
   
  for i in range(2, N + 1) :
   
    if (SumOfPrimeDivisors[i] == 0) :
       
        for j in range(i, N + 1, i) :
           
            SumOfPrimeDivisors[j] += i
           
  return SumOfPrimeDivisors[N]

arr=[]   
for i in range(18,26):
   if isPrime(i):
      arr.append(0)
   else:
      arr.append(Sum(i))
print(arr)
```